# Queen Victoria and the Tsar’s faberge egg

Tags: united-kingdom

In the movie *Victoria and Abdul* Queen Victoria say’s she regrets shattering the Tsars faberge egg.
Which Tsar was it and why did she shatter it?

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely pure fiction. Faberge made his famous eggs for Russian royal family since 1885. Out of all of pre-1901 (i.e made before Queen Victoria's death) Faberge-made imperial eggs only one is not accounted for in lists of tzar's property seized by the Soviets during the Russian Revolution - the [Mauve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauve_(Faberg%C3%A9_egg)) egg, made in 1897. All other eggs are traceable at least until 1922. Could Victoria have that egg shattered? Definitely not by her own hand - first, none of the eggs are known to leave Russia before the Revolution, and she never visited Russia in person; second - there is no record of how the egg was lost, and its destruction by the English Queen would definitely had been notable enough to leave a trace in history.

On the other hand, Queen might've referred metaphorically to one of the several occasions she disrupted Russian Emperors' plans - in time of her rule, Britain's and Russia's interests often clashed. In this case, from this short phrase it's impossible to tell which of four Russian Emperors whose time in power intersected with her own she meant.

Comment: Nice last observation. So this is how the royals talk about this kind of *business*? "Go get cousin Willy and hit him in his *Faberge eggs* until he returns Belgium?"